# jQuery Slider Speeds Up

Tags: jquery, carousel, coda-slider

Why does the jQuery  Slider [on this page](http://tinyurl.com/od5kzf9) keep speeding up? If I leave the page open for a while, continue to work in another tab and then come back to the page, the speed of the slider has increased enormously. 
The Jquery Slider that is being used is the Coda Slider. The .js file [can be found here](http://tinyurl.com/oezp9om).

What is going wrong here? I can't seem to find this problem anywhere else on the internet. Neither with other JQuery sliders.

I've tried moving the `easing.js` above the `codaslider.js`, but it does not help.

Comment: There seems to be something thats over-riding the interval set. Only thing i got is the order of `jquery.easing.js` and `coda-slider plugin js`. Can you push the easing above the slider plugin and see? Also : https://github.com/kevinbatdorf/codaslider/issues

Comment: does increasing the slideEaseDuration value make much difference?

Comment: It may be the trigger on line 190 that is causing problems. That's where I would start debugging. You set a timeout there, and then set it again within the autoslide function on line 203. Unless this is not your code? then as Roy mentioned, you may be overriding something...

Comment: This indeed is not my code. Ill try to push the easing.js above the coda slider and see if it works! Thanks